# CSS style attributes not applying correctly

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="inner_header">
        <div class="text">
            <h1>My<span>Site</span></h1>
                </div>
                <ul class="navigation">
                    <a><li>Youtube</a></li>
                    <a><li>Discord</a></li>
                    <a><li>Github</a></li>
                </ul>
                
            </div>
           </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation a{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    

}

.navigation a li{
    background-color: teal;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Fjalla One;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

For the very last one (.navigation a li)
NONE of the attributes apply, does anyone know why?

I am not sure why this is happening but it would be extremely helpful if I could get a response. It is probably some stupid bug that I am not aware of(yes I have tried debugging).

Comment: Typo: you have your start and end tags messed up for the list items `<a><li>Youtube</a></li>` should be `<li><a href="">Text</a></li>`

Comment: I was right! It was some stupid bug. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.navigation{
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.navigation a{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    

}

.navigation li a{
    background-color: teal;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-family: Fjalla One;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner_header">
    <div class="text">
      <h1>My<span>Site</span></h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a>Youtube</a></li>
      <li><a>Discord</a></li>
      <li class="className"><a>Github</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Your HTML structure is wrong actually. The structure needs to be like that way.

Answer (score 0):

`<a><li>Youtube</a></li>`
is not correctlly formated HTML, try like this
`<li><a>Youtube</a></li>` and update your CSS to address `.navigation li a`

Comment: You wrap the content of the list item in `<li>`, `<li>` doesn't go in `<a>`.

Comment: @imvain2, yea correct. Typing on my mobile, made typo with cut and paste. Corrected, thx :)